# Why data is different in Next Page Flow Report and PageView report?

Tags: adobe-analytics

This is related to Site-Catalyst reporting.
I was looking into 'Next Page Flow Report' for a particular page. The report says, for a particular time duration, the total path views were **4500**. But when I looked into 'pageViews' report of the same page, it says, the pageViews of that page for the same duration was **5,000**. Ideally, the pageViews and path views should match, since anyone who landed on that page (which is pageview) must either exit or should navigate to any next page (which comes in next page flow report). Not sure, why this difference is coming then.

Does anyone has any idea about this ? Please help.

Thanks,
Adwait

Answer (score 0):

For example, let's say you have 3 pages, and lets say that individually (looking at pages report), each page had 10 page views:

```
PageA : 10 page views
PageB : 10 page views
PageC : 10 page views
```

In your pages report, you should see it just like that.  But page views within a *pathing* report are shown in relation to *paths*, not standalone page views. So for example, one path could be:

```
PageA (3 page views) > PageB (4 page views) > (exited site)
```

This just shows how many people took the same path throughout your site, where they diverged, etc..think of it like a choose-your-own-adventure book, where at each point of the story, the reader can choose which way the story goes, so that overall, there are different permutations of the story. A website works in much the same way. Visitors can start off on virtually any page accessible on your site (though usually the homepage or landing pages are the most common), and from there, they navigate to wherever else on your site.

So, if you were to add up the page views for PageA for *all* the paths, it should match what's in the base pages report, but if you are looking at page views for an individual path, it's not going to add up, because it's just page views for that page that happened in that one path (well, it's theoretically possible for them to match, e.g. if there's only one path, but that's highly unlikely to actually happen).

Answer (score 0):

Path Views will always report Pure Page Views (yes, I call it Pure).

What does this mean?  Well, it simply means that the Path Views for a Page is equal to the Total Page Views less the Reloads of that Page for a specific period.

Therefore, if your Path Views are 4500, and Page Views are 5000, then this means that your page was reloaded 500 times.